# How to do FIltering in outliner using 2 keyword to search 2 different object types at the same time?

Tags: outliner

For example in outliner : i only want to show 'plane' and 'point light' in the list. How can i do this ? the only solution is having 2 outliner for each keyword.
I tried 'plane,point' or 'plane;point' but no luck.

Does anyone know the correct syntax ? or it's not supported ?

Thanks